# What is purpose of sideway transformer in PSU?

Tags: power-supply

In another question someone ask about repair of laptop PSU. I cannot find it ATM - possibly because it was closed as about repair and off topic.

However an attached schematic to one of the answers had a sideway transformer (XFRM1 on schematic below)) surrounded by 2 caps (C1 and C2) before transformer to (I presume) lower the voltage. As far as I can tell it doesn't 'do anything' which leads me to think it may be a safety feature. What may be a purpose of it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQBsux.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It is a common-mode choke. [This post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202267/common-mode-chokes-and-their-selection) might have some useful details

Comment: see also here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331177/why-are-the-transformer-windings-in-series-with-line-and-load-in-this-circuit

Comment: @P2000 voted to close as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

It is a common mode choke, and it works to prevent high frequencies conducting back to mains. It is required for switch mode power supplies to pass the required electromagnetic interference tests.

Comment: except that this is not a switched mode power supply, and perhaps it is used as a line filter to reject incoming line noise, as common in audio applications and measurement equipment